# What does "get a line in" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Old Guard (2020)*, Andy injured by gun shot:

> Dr Meta: I need to **get a line in her** and stop the  bleeding.
>
> Merrick: Keep her alive at all costs.

What does "get a line in" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctor wants to put the injured person on a saline drip, to replace fluids lost through heavy bleeding.

Comment: Great answer. “Get a line in” might also refer to whole blood as well as saline or ringer’s lactate. Although, in the case of heavy bleeding, the fluid would be replaced quicker than a drip to avoid shock from the blood pressure loss. One way of doing this is to bolus (squeeze) the IV bag.

Answer (score -2):

get a line on smb/smth

informal
learn something about
(New Oxford American Dictionary, 3rd Edition © 2010)

Comment: The question was about _get a line in_, not _on_.